# Combine data segment and bss segment

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

Why the process creates two segments for the program variables, I mean data segment and BSS segment. In other world, since they are both intended to represent the program's variables and also are both Read/Write segments why they are not just combined in one segment?

Answer (score 0):

Data in the `.data` segment has different values determined when the executable file itsself is created, i.e., at build time, which includes compile and linking time.
It is stored directly in the executable file and therefore **consumes space in it and the core image loaded into memory**.

OTOH, data in the `.bss` segment has the value zero by default (even though I think some pre-DOS OSes left the value uninitialized but zero is enforced by the C and C++ standards anyway). As opposed to data in `.data`, which may have a variety of values, one for each datum, data in `.bss` need not be initialized explicitly with arbitrary values. In conclusion, **variables from** `.bss` **do not consume space in an executable file or the core image**. They are created at runtime by the OS.

These properties render merging both segments infeasible. At the cost of an increased core image, the `.bss` section could be eliminated, but that would defeat the purpose of it.